# Issue removing border from one column in primefaces table

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I am beginning to realize just how terrible I am at CSS now that i've decided to start using the prime-faces library.  I have a 3 column table, the third column of which i would like to use as an optional error field.  I do not want this field to show up as part of the table, even when the error is rendered.  However after searching and finding a few solutions online, I still cannot get the border style to be overridden.  Here is a sample of my markup.

Its the "noCellBorder" column I want to have no styles or borders of any kind:

```html
<p:panelGrid>

  <f:facet name="header">
    <p:row>
      <p:column>Month</p:column>
      <p:column>Amount</p:column>
    </p:row>
  </f:facet>

  <p:row>
    <p:column>
      <h:outputLabel class="rightLabelPadding" for="formLine1">
        <h:outputText value="#{labels.formLine1}" escape="false" />
      </h:outputLabel>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
      <p:inputText id="formLine1" value="#{managedBean.formBean.line1}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="noCellBorder">
      <h:message class="fieldErrorMessage" for="formLine1" />
    </p:column>
  </p:row>
```

**CSS**

```
.noCellBorder > td {
  border: none !important;
}
```

EDIT //

Okay not all is a total loss I suppose I've learned how to use JSFiddle.  I haven't had to really delve too deeply into CSS in at least 2 years so please go easy on me.  Here is the link to a working demo:

[Removed by OP]

Comment: Create a demo with *static/generated* HTML and CSS.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by demo

Comment: I meant that you need to show us the issue using SO snippet or use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am still unclear as to how to do that.  This is using PrimeFaces components that are rendered as HTML markup and custom styles as defined by the toolkit.  I tried entering the same thing i've provided here in the JSFiddle tool and unsuprisingly it was not able to render.

Comment: Yes, that means you will need to use the rendered HTML in JSfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other classes for header and row give borders too, so you have to get rid of them like this (give your panelGrid class `noBroder` like this `<p:panelGrid styleClass="noBorder">`)

```
.noCellBorder, table.noBorder thead tr.ui-widget-header, table.noBorder .ui-panelgrid-even, table.noBorder .ui-panelgrid-odd {
     border: none !important;
}
```

But is gives black borders for other cells, don't know if you like it.

Comment: Fixed - only `<p:panelGrid>` with class `noBorder` affected.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using descendant/child selector but it is required to use multiple CSS selector since you are targeting the `td` element which has a class `.noCellBorder`

```
td.noCellBorder{
  border: none !important;
}
```

Also try to avoid `!important` and increase CSS specificity, so your code should be.

```
td.ui-panelgrid-cell.noCellBorder {
  border: none;
}
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/uamxqp64/3/)

**Modified Code:**

```css
.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
td.ui-panelgrid-cell.noCellBorder {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="formNC3Form:j_id_10_1_4" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget" role="grid">
  <thead class="ui-panelgrid-header">
    <tr class="ui-widget-header" role="row">
      <td role="columnheader" class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-widget-header">Month</td>
      <td role="columnheader" class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-widget-header">Amount</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-panelgrid-even" role="row">
      <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <label class="rightLabelPadding" for="formNC3Form:formNC3Line1">1. January</label>
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <input id="formNC3Form:formNC3Line1" name="formNC3Form:formNC3Line1" type="text" value="" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell noCellBorder"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Something else must be happening because while that works in the example I provided, it was not sufficient in my working code-base.  Let me see if i can add more of the primefaces styling

Comment: ive included every single style mentioned in the markup and still I cannot get this to work.  I am very ready to rip out these primefaces tags and just go with plain JSF.  This is extremely frustrating.  Thank you for your help.  I am sure it is simply a case of me not including enough information

Comment: No problem. Hope you find a solution soon.